# Queries regarding ros2 example

Tags: ros2

```
import rclpy
from rclpy.node import Node

from std_msgs.msg import String


class MinimalPublisher(Node):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('minimal_publisher')
        self.publisher_ = self.create_publisher(String, 'topic', 10)
        timer_period = 0.5  # seconds
        self.timer = self.create_timer(timer_period, self.timer_callback)
        self.i = 0

    def timer_callback(self):
        msg = String()
        msg.data = 'Hello World: %d' % self.i
        self.publisher_.publish(msg)
        self.get_logger().info('Publishing: "%s"' % msg.data)
        self.i += 1

def main(args=None):
    rclpy.init(args=args)

    minimal_publisher = MinimalPublisher()

    rclpy.spin(minimal_publisher)
    minimal_publisher.destroy_node()
    rclpy.shutdown()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Q1: `from std_msgs.msg import String` Here is string a class or something else?

Q2: `self.publisher_.publish(msg)` Here, is .publish a method of Node class? I cannot find this method inside the Node class documentation. https://docs.ros2.org/foxy/api/rclpy/api/node.html

Q3: Where can I find details about the string similar to the Node class link above? I can only find this link - https://docs.ros2.org/foxy/api/example_interfaces/msg/String.html

How can I find different methods/attributes of String besides the .data attribute similar to the Node class?

Q4: `self.get_logger().info('Publishing: "%s"' % msg.data)` I have found the get_logger. Where does the .info come from?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange! 
All your questions are related to Python and don't seem related to ROS. There is no harm in these questions, but I strongly recommend spending some time with Python programming. ROS 2 intensely uses Object-oriented programming (OOP), so please get familiar with it.

Answer (score 1):

**Q1:** yes. It is defined [here](https://github.com/ros2/rclpy/blob/df92d9e27c3d62bb764ab512ff7e1c53d93c9af1/rclpy/rclpy/node.py#L107)

**Q2:** No, publish is a method of the Publisher class. You call it on `self.publisher_`, which is a Publisher (as opposed to `self`, which is a node).

**Q3:** The ROS 2 python classes are in the `rclpy` package, see [this github repository](https://github.com/ros2/rclpy/tree/rolling/rclpy/rclpy). E.g. the Publisher class is inside [publisher.py](https://github.com/ros2/rclpy/blob/df92d9e27c3d62bb764ab512ff7e1c53d93c9af1/rclpy/rclpy/publisher.py#L27),

The `String` class belongs to the `std_msgs` module (see the line: `from std_msgs.msg import String`). `std_msgs` is the 'standard messages' definition. Message types are generated from message deescrtiption files, see the [documentation](https://docs.ros.org/en/iron/Tutorials/Beginner-Client-Libraries/Custom-ROS2-Interfaces.html). I'm not sure where the generated python files are located in a binary install, but you can locate them by opening a terminal and issuing `locate site-packages/std_msgs |grep \.py$`

**Q4:** Have a look a the [logging documentation](https://docs.ros.org/en/iron/Concepts/Intermediate/About-Logging.html).